# Table is no longer valid to operate on, on AsyncTask

Tags: android, realm

I'm having a real hard time to make Realm work on Async Task, and so far, I was not able to make it work.

So, this is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
private class saveOnRealmAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Transactions>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Transactions> doInBackground(Void... Void) {
        //make a list of object to save on Realms
        return listObjectToSave; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Transactions> listObjectToSave) {
        super.onPostExecute(transactionsList);
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(listObjectToSave);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();

        hideProgressDialog();

        activity.finish();

    }
}
```

I'm got a

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal State: Table is no longer valid to operate on."

on `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(listObjectToSave);`

It works when I do this outside of an AsyncTask, but the problem is, some times, it take some times to get my list object ready to save.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're writing to the Realm on the UI thread. You should do that on the background thread.

```
private class saveOnRealmAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... Void) {
        //make a list of object to save on Realms
        final fListObjectToSave = listObjectToSave;
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(fListObjectToSave);
                }
            });
        } finally {
            if(realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked like that. I had other problems, but it was related to the object that i was trying to save that used other Realm Object as field and I manage to get it work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can access realm only from the thread on which you created it. Asynctask executes on another thread so it crashes. If you want asynchron saving use async transactions instead

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
        //save here
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(listObjectToSave);
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        //callback for success
    }
});
```

Check [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-transactions) for more info

Comment: But if he closes the Realm before `OnSuccess` is called by the asynchronous transaction callback, then he'll run into issues.

Comment: yea the realm needs to be closed in onSuccess

Comment: Or also in `onError()`